# Вечный цикл + cron реально?

Tags: php, cron

Всем добрый вечер. Запускаю скрипт через cron каждую минуту. За эту минуту нужно сделать несколько операций с разрывом в 10 сек.

Делаю это так

```
set_time_limit(60);
while(true) {
echo "Test";
sleep(10);
echo "Test";
}
```

Но почему то сообщение выводиться только 1 раз. Что делаю не так?

Comment: надо пользоваться flush() или ob_flush() чтоб с буфера всё выплюнуть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, после каждого вывода сообщения прописать?

Comment: cron запускает скрипты без привязки к терминалу. Куда он у вас выводит сообщение? В лог?

Comment: @vp_arth, это для примера код. На самом деле он выполняет функцию

Comment: Как вы понимаете, что функция отработала? Сколько по времени она выполняется? Если запускаете без cron, всё работает?

Comment: @vp_arth, Как я пониманию - скрипт отправляет сообщение в Вк. Раз оно пришло - значит скрипт выполнился. Без крона вечная загрузка идет.

Comment: "вечная загрузка идёт" - это значит работает? Сообщения отправляются? Или просто скрипт висит и ничего не происходит?

Comment: @vp_arth, а нет. нет вечной загрузки и скрипт работает - при прямом обращении отправляется 1 сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php) относится не к реальному времени, а к времени работы самого php. sleep и другие операции ввода-вывода не считаются.

Предлагаю более точный подход:

```
$start = microtime(true); // засекаем время начала
do {
  doSomething(); // вызов вашей функции
  sleep(10);
} while (microtime(true) - $start < 60); // прошла ли минута?
```

В остальном, нужно дебажить скрипт в отрыве от крона, корректно обрабатывать ошибки - возможно сервисы, к которым вы обращаетесь, ограничивают рейт обращений.

---

Запуск крона каждые 15 секунд:

```
* * * * * your_script
* * * * * sleep 15; your_script
* * * * * sleep 30; your_script
* * * * * sleep 45; your_script
```

Comment: doSomething(); - здесь писать свою функцию?

Comment: Да, разумеется.

Comment: Странно, но все равно срабатывает только 1 раз

Comment: Может можно изменить решение задачи, как сделать так, чтобы крон выполнялся каждые 15 сек ?

Comment: Спасибо, вариант с отложенным кроном решил проблему